# type hint definitions for the MutableMapping pop() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I was investigating the [`typing.pyi` file](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/typing.pyi) to gain a better understanding of how the generic container type hinting works, and came upon the following lines in the `MutableMapping` class definition:

```
@overload
def pop(self, k: _KT) -> _VT: ...
@overload
def pop(self, k: _KT, default: Union[_VT, _T] = ...) -> Union[_VT, _T]: ...
```

The part of this I do not understand is the `_T` additional parameter. Only two parameters can be specified for `MutableMapping`: `_KT` and `_VT`. This extra `_T` parameter, then, remains unspecified. How does the type checker go about resolving this 3rd type...?

Comment: `_VT` isn't a parameter type in the first definition, it's the return type. In the second definition `_T` would be the type of a default value that's *different* to the usual value type of the mapping - the default value can either be of the usual value type `_VT` or a different type `_T`, hence the `Union`, and so can the resulting returned result. If you don't specify the default, it either returns `_VT` or errors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see. In this context is the _T return type covariant...? Does the return type have to be the same type as default or just a compatible subtype?

Comment: @jonrsharpe also: I meant that _VT is a parameter to be passed to the MM generic class when you use it, eg: `class M(MutableMapping[int, int]):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was originally going to leave this in a comment, but my answer started to become a bit long, so here it is...

> Only two parameters can be specified for MutableMapping: _KT and _VT. This extra _T parameter, then, remains unspecified. How does the type checker go about resolving this 3rd type...?

As @jonrsharpe basically said, `_T` is *not* a class type parameter, it's a function type parameter. Basically, when you call that method, mypy will have:

1. Already bound `_KT` and `_VT` to some other type. So, if we do `foo: MutableMapping[str, int] = ...` then call `foo.pop(...)`, mypy will understand that `_KT` and `_VT` are bound to `str` and `int` respectively at the time we call `pop`.
2. Mypy will additionally notice that we have a *free* (aka *unbound*) type parameter floating around if we call the second overload. It will then attempt to *infer* what the correct type of `_T` is based on whatever value we pass in/the surrounding context.

   For example, suppose I do `foo.pop("x", "bar")`. This matches the second overload. We also previously said that `_KT` and `_VT` are bound to `str` and `int` respectively. Mypy then notices that `_T` is unbound and tries to infer an appropriate type.

   Here, we know that the value we're passing in is of type "str" and that the parameter type is `Union[int, _T]` (after substituting in the bound types). We also know that the value we pass in must be a *subtype* of the parameters -- we know that `str` must be a subtype of `Union[int, _T]`.

   Mypy then runs an inference algorithm using all of the above info/all of the known constraints and is able to infer in this case that `_T` must be of type `str`.

(As a side note, mypy's inference algorithm here isn't perfect. It may sometimes fail to infer the correct type if the expression is particularly complex/currently doesn't correctly handle certain edge cases.)

If you want a more detailed description of how exactly mypy's type inference algorithm works, you can try spelunking through mypy's codebase. Specifically, mypy calls [this function](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/infer.py) which in turn calls [code in here](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/constraints.py). Fair warning, it's a bit difficult to understand.

> In this context is the _T return type covariant...?

We know here that `_KT`, `_VT`, and `_T` are all invariant based on [their definition](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/typing.pyi#L57).

Each of those three type variables can be completely independent from one another. This matches the runtime behavior: if I have a `Dict[str, str]`, doing `my_dict.pop("x", 4)` could return either some string or the number 4 depending on what exactly `my_dict` contains.

> Does the return type have to be the same type as default or just a compatible subtype?

So setting aside generics completely, here are the (simplified) rules for overloads as of mypy 0.620. (Older versions of mypy used a similar but more fluffier, ad-hoc algorithm).

1. By default, mypy will let the return types of any two overloads be completely arbitrary: they don't need to have any inherent relationship to each other.
2. Mypy however will prohibit *inherently unsafe* overload definitions. Two overload variants are considered inherently unsafe if:

   1. All of the arguments of the first variant are compatible with the second.
   2. The return type of the first variant is not compatible with (e.g. is not a subtype of) the second.

   In the specific case of `pop`, the arguments of the first variant are indeed compatible with the second: for whatever reason, the `default` argument is marked as optional. This means a call to `foo.pop("x")` can actually match both overloads.

   However, the the first overload variant's return type *is* a subtype of the second's: `_VT` is a subtype of `Union[_VT, _T]` no matter what `_T` ends up being.
3. When you actually call an overload, mypy will check the available overloads in the order that they are defined and use the first variant that matches. To make sure this algorithm behaves as expected, mypy will report an error if the overloads are defined in a way such that it's impossible for some variants to ever be matched.

These rules don't really change in a significant way if we add generics into the mix.

The documentation has more details/more examples about [the nuances of function overloading](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#function-overloading).

Comment: Excellent. Lots of detailed info to learn from better. Love it.